# Getting count of files in directory using Go

Tags: go

How might I get the count of items returned by io/ioutil.ReadDir()?

I have this code, which works, but I have to think isn't the RightWay(tm) in Go.

```
package main

import "io/ioutil"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    files,_ := ioutil.ReadDir("/Users/dgolliher/Dropbox/INBOX")
    var count int
    for _, f := range files {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
        count++
    }
    fmt.Println(count)
}
```

Lines 8-12 seem like way too much to go through to just count the results of ReadDir, but I can't find the correct syntax to get the count without iterating over the range.  Help?

Comment: If you are strictly looking for a count, you should look at using [File.Readdirnames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames). This avoids collecting the information on every file. Walking the files ([filepath.Walk](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk)) would have presumably been even more efficient, but underlying that is also Readdirnames.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.   In the application I developed, I wouldl expect a trivial optimization from changing my implementation at this point.  I'll file this suggestion away for next time!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the answer in http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

```
package main

import "io/ioutil"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    files,_ := ioutil.ReadDir("/Users/dgolliher/Dropbox/INBOX")
    fmt.Println(len(files))
}
```

Comment: Both `ioutil.ReadDir` and `os.ReadDir` do sorting which we don't need. Also `ioutil.ReadDir` is deprecated for some reason. We better off calling `os.Open` then `f.Readdirnames(-1)`. I have posted a complete example as an answer.

Comment: Deprecated https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil@go1.22.1#ReadDir

Answer (score 8):

ReadDir returns a list of *directory entries* sorted by filename, so it is not just files. Here is a little function for those wanting to get a count of files only (and not dirs):

```
func fileCount(path string) (int, error){
    i := 0
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() { 
            i++
        }
    }
    return i, nil
}
```

Comment: Both `ioutil.ReadDir` and `os.ReadDir` do sorting which we don't need. Also `ioutil.ReadDir` is deprecated for some reason. We better off calling `os.Open` then `f.Readdirnames(-1)`. I have posted a complete example as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Go 1.16 (Feb 2021), a better option is `os.ReadDir`:

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   d, e := os.ReadDir(".")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(len(d))
}
```

`os.ReadDir` returns `fs.DirEntry` instead of `fs.FileInfo`, which means that
`Size` and `ModTime` methods are omitted, making the process more efficient if
you just need an entry count.

https://golang.org/pkg/os#ReadDir

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get all files (not recursive) you can use len(files). If you need to just get the files without folders and hidden files just loop over them and increase a counter. And please don’t ignore errors

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code of [ioutil.ReadDir](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19.1:src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go)

```
func ReadDir(dirname string) ([]fs.FileInfo, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    list, err := f.Readdir(-1)
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    sort.Slice(list, func(i, j int) bool { return list[i].Name() < list[j].Name() })
    return list, nil
}
```

you would realize that it calls `os.File.Readdir()` then sorts the files.

In case of counting it, you don't need to sort, so you are better off calling `os.File.Readdir()` directly.
You can simply copy and paste this function then remove the sort.
But I did find out that `f.Readdirnames(-1)` is much faster than `f.Readdir(-1)`.
Running time is almost half for `/usr/bin/` with 2808 items (16ms vs 35ms).
So to summerize it in an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    list, err := f.Readdirnames(-1)
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(list))
}
```